# iOS problems sharing data between view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, share, segue, viewdidload

I'm having problems passing data between two view controllers.

I've seen two ways to do this.

One involves implementing `prepareForSeque:` in the segue's source view controller and another involves setting properties in the `viewDidLoad:` method of the segue's destination view controller.

e.g.-

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toEmailReservationViewController"]) {
        FLSendEmailViewController *controller = (FLSendEmailViewController     *)segue.destinationViewController;
        if (!controller.startDateField.text) {

            controller.startDateField.text = @"today";
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.startDateField.text = ((FLViewController   *)self.presentingViewController).startDate;
}
```

I've got these to work on simple apps using two `UIViewController`.  However, I can't get them to work on an app that has a `UITabViewController` connected to some `UINavigationViewController` connected to custom subclasses of `UIViewController`.  When I click the button to perform the push seque, I get to the view I want, but the `startDateField.text` doesn't have the text from the segue's source view controller.

Why are these methods of sharing data not working with the `tab controller` and `navigation controller` setup?

I noticed that in `prepareForSegue:` I can't set `controller.startDateField.text`; as shown when I try to set it and use NSLog to display it.  Could this be the problem?  Is it possible that the property controller.startDateField.text doesn't exist yet?

I'm trying to grab the date from a datePicker in an instance of FLViewController, store this date in the property `NSString *startDate`, and in an instance of FLSendEmailViewController set `NSString *startDateField.text` to the `NSString *startDate'.

Here are the UIViewController subclasses I created:

FLViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "FLSendEmailViewController.h"

// import frameworks to use ad
@import AddressBook;
@import AddressBookUI;

@interface FLViewController : UIViewController

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScroller;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *startDate;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *stopDate;

    - (IBAction)exitToReservations:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender;

@end
```

FLViewController.m

```
#import "FLViewController.h"

@interface FLViewController ()

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *startReservationDatePicker;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *stopReservationDatePicker;

@end

@implementation FLViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.theScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [self.theScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(280, 1000)];

        //setup reservationDatePicker
        [self.startReservationDatePicker addTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(startDatePickerChanged:)
                                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self.stopReservationDatePicker addTarget:self
                                           action:@selector(stopDatePickerChanged:)
                                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // add method called when user changes start date
    - (void)startDatePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFortmatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFortmatter setDateFormat:@"dd--MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
        // get date using stringFromData: method and getter datePicker.date
        self.startDate = [dateFortmatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
        NSLog(@"The start date is %@", self.startDate);
    }

    // add method called when user changes stop date
    - (void)stopDatePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFortmatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFortmatter setDateFormat:@"dd--MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
        // get date using stringFromData: method and getter datePicker.date
        self.stopDate= [dateFortmatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
        NSLog(@"The stop date is %@", self.stopDate);

    }

    - (IBAction)exitToReservations:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender {
        // execute this code upon unwinding
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toEmailReservationViewController"]) {
            FLSendEmailViewController *controller = (FLSendEmailViewController         *)segue.destinationViewController;
            if (!controller.startDateField.text) {

                controller.startDateField.text = @"today";
                NSLog(@"in vc startDate is null but set to %@",controller.startDateField.text );
            }
        }
    }
@end
```

FLSendEmailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FLViewController;

    @interface FLSendEmailViewController : UIViewController

    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *startDateField;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *stopDateField;

@end
```

FLSendEmailViewController.m

```
#import "FLSendEmailViewController.h"
#import "FLViewController.h"

@interface FLSendEmailViewController ()

    - (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberOfDoggies;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailAddressField;

    - (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation FLSendEmailViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.startDateField.text = ((FLViewController *)self.presentingViewController).startDate;

    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender {
        NSString *emailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I would like you to watch my %@ doggies from %@ to %@.  Thank you.", self.numberOfDoggies.text, self.startDateField.text, self.stopDateField.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",emailString);
    }
    - (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {

        [self.startDateField resignFirstResponder];
    }
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import the `FLSendEmailViewController.h` to the "InitialViewController.h"
2. Add this property to the `FLSendEmailViewController.h`

   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *exportedData;
3. Add this to the `FLSendEmailViewController.m`

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.startDateField.text = self.exportedData
   }
   ```

4.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toEmailReservationViewController"]) {
    FLSendEmailViewController *controller = (FLSendEmailViewController     *)segue.destinationViewController;
    if (!controller.startDateField.text) {

        controller.exportedData = @"today";
    }

}
}
```

Comment: This is good.  Thanks.  But what if I want to set `controller.exportedData` to the value of an NSString property in the segue's source view controller?

Comment: I just answered my last question. If in the segue's source view controller there is the property `NSString *startDate`, then set `controller.exportedData = self.startDate`.  Make sure the startDate property has the value you want in it before you assign it to `controller.exportedData`.

Answer (score 0):

This "*sharing method*" **works in any case when from a controller go to another controller**.

So, in case of a `navigation controller`, if you want **push another `viewController`** **passing the data**, you have just to **set the trigger in the Storyboard** (if you are using storyboard) **from the button, and the new `viewController`**.

So, you will not met troubles. Otherwise, you are committing other type of errors, and in this case, update your question.

Comment: I've added the UIViewController subclasses and made a couple of new notes.  I still haven't solved my problem.  Thanks for your help.